# MVC music store I can't find any update for the album table to adjust the inventory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, model-view-controller

I am using the MVC music store example to create a web store but I can't find anywhere in the example some code to substract the article I have chosen in the cart from the Album table.   Do you know if this code exist or it was never created ?

Example, I bought 3 disk of ABBA, The table Album should be substract from 3 somewhere which I can't find.

Normally when you create the CART you should check if the inventory of the article is greater than the item count.  Also when you are create the checkout you should subtract the article count from the Album table.

Anyone will have an example to share to see this part ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no Inventory Tracking feature in the Music Store source. This is the source I looked at: https://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/

The Album table only stores specs, not inventory counts.

However, Inventory Tracking would be trivial to add. Give it a try.

Comment: same source for me. Do you know any other example where they handle the inventory tracking ?  I will like to see an example as I am new to MVC. A webstore should take care of the inventory also. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197427/mvc3-how-to-update-stock-of-multiple-items

Comment: I was also checking the same questions !!!  If you find anything else let me know